# Where in select using Phantom doesn't resolve

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I have been toying around with the smiple code provided in the phantom wiki, the follow I have tried;

```
import com.websudos.phantom.dsl._

case class Student(id: UUID, name: String)

class Students extends CassandraTable[Students, Student] {
  object id extends UUIDColumn(this) with PartitionKey[UUID]
  object name extends StringColumn(this)

  def fromRow(row: Row): Student = {
    Student(id(row), name(row))
  }
}

object Students extends Students with Connector {

  def getByName(name: String): Future[Option[Student]] = {
    select.where(_.name eqs name).one()
  }
}
```

But my IDE keeps saying `Cannot resolve symbol where` and the compiler says `value where is not a member of com.websudos.phantom.builder.query.RootSelectBlock[Students,Student]`

I'm using Scala `2.11.6` and Phantom `1.10.1`, all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue and resolved this using @flavian's suggestion above.

Ensure that your `Connector` has an implicit keyspace defined.

This is directly lifted from the example project.

```
trait KeyspaceDefinition {
  implicit val keySpace = KeySpace("sample_keyspace")
}

trait Connector extends SimpleConnector with KeyspaceDefinition
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing out on a fundamental Cassandra issue, you cannot query by `name` as it's not an indexed column. Based on the table you've just defined, the query you are trying to perform is invalid and Cassandra will tell you that at runtime.

Phantom will prevent most bad things at compile time. It's worth reading through [this blog series](http://blog.websudos.com/2014/08/16/a-series-on-cassandra-part-1-getting-rid-of-the-sql-mentality/) to understand how things work in Cassandra.

To put things in perspective, the only `where` query that's valid for your `Students` table is:

```
def getById(id: UUID): Future[Option[Student]] = {
  select.where(_.id eqs id).one()
}
```

Comment: Even when changing it to `id` it is still throwing compile errors about `where` not being a member of `select`

Comment: @Liam Then you don't have an `implicit session` or `implicit keySpace` in scope. You need both for phantom queries to compile. Where are you copying your example from?

Comment: @LiamHaworth If you read the comments on top of that line, it's telling you that a compiler error will be produced. I think that wasn't obvious enough, I will try to re-phrase it.

Comment: Is it possible to return Future[Student]?  And if it doesn't find it just be a Failure?

Comment: Hi @coolbreeze it's easy to implement but not currently in the default API, I've added a ticket for a new method that does this for people who prefer a different API flavour.